# How do I align an image to the left and text to the right without it wrapping? On Big Cartel custom page

Tags: css, bigcartel

I'm using Big Cartel free, on a custom page, so I can only edit CSS. Anything I add to the custom page stays in one span:

```
<section id="page_body">
 <p>
  <span>...</span> [image and text are both in this span]
 </p>
</section>
```

It automatically wraps [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N8cIc.png), but is it possible to make the image stay on the left and have the text start at the top of the right column [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yHTIL.png)?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can `float` the image, seems to have the effect you want. You can add padding below the image so that text won't wrap into below it.

```html
<section id="page_body">
  <p>
    <span>
    
      <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/N8cIc.png" style="width:120px; float:left; padding-bottom:120px; margin-right: 10px;">
      
        lorem ipsum dolo rkas wiej skdksjd ksdj skd j lorem ipsum dolo rkas wiej skdksjd ksdj skd j lorem ipsum dolo rkas wiej skdksjd ksdj skd j lorem ipsum dolo rkas wiej skdksjd ksdj skd j lorem ipsum dolo rkas wiej skdksjd ksdj skd j lorem ipsum dolo rkas wiej skdksjd ksdj skd j lorem ipsum dolo rkas wiej skdksjd ksdj skd j lorem ipsum dolo rkas wiej skdksjd ksdj skd j lorem ipsum dolo rkas wiej skdksjd ksdj skd j lorem ipsum dolo rkas wiej skdksjd ksdj skd j lorem ipsum dolo rkas wiej skdksjd ksdj skd j lorem ipsum dolo rkas wiej skdksjd ksdj skd j
      <div style="clear:both"></div>
    
    </span>
  </p>
  after
</section>
```

Comment: I'm unable to edit the html, but ended up solving it by just changing changing the span display, but thank you!

For anyone that needs:
span {
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 5px;
}